# Jquery rotate divs

Tags: jquery, html, rotation

i have question because i can´t find one plugin in jquery for do this

I need have for example 10 divs containers , these divs show with float left with his id , etc , i need plugin or something can show the number i want from this 10 , 20 , etc divs and show in groups of 4 , 3 , or the number i want and rotate or move

For example show first 4 divs and after 8 , ..... etc and select the effect for this transition

I need this , i see many plugins but no works for show this , also if this plugin or script , etc can let manual ( manual or auto rotate - no search sliders )  move with arrows etc perfect  but the most important show only the number of divs i want and rotate these and show the other divs and when go to the end show other time the first div , etc

Thank´s sorry if no understand perfectly all

Regards !!!

Comment: You question is still unclear. What do you want? Do you want to rotate particular div after certain time interval or something else?

Comment: no only rotate divs each certain time or have posibility of rotate in manual mode

Answer (score 1):

[QTransform](https://github.com/puppybits/QTransform) allows you to rotate, skew, scale and translate and it works cross browser.

Download and inlcude the `QTransform.js` to your html.

`<script src="js/qTransform.js"></script>`

Provide a fixed height-width to your div(s) and add the following script:

```
$('#box4').delay(300).animate({rotate: '20deg'}, 500);
$('#box5').delay(700).animate({rotate: '50deg'}, 500);
$('#box6').delay(1200).animate({rotate: '80deg'}, 500);
```

where (box4, box5 & box6 are my div id's). 

The `delay(300), delay(700) & delay(1200)` starts the animation after 300, 500 and 1200 milliseconds. And the 500 at the end is the duration for the animation.

If you want to manually provide the rotation angle you can do like this:

Take the angle in variable. e.g.

```
var degAngle = 60;
```

and add it to the script like

```
$('#box4').delay(300).animate({rotate: degAngle+'deg'}, 500);
```

You can also provide the multiple effects like scale along with rotation. E.g.,

```
$('#box4').delay(300).animate({scale: '1.5', rotate: '20deg'}, 500);
```

**Why QTransform?**

Till date jQuery doesn't support CSS3 animations. This plugin can help you to accomplish your target.

Hope this works for you.